# How to upload a folder in django

Tags: python, django

As a newbie to django, I'm having an insanely difficult time figuring out how to upload a folder to the site directory with django. Let me give some context. I'm making a sort of blog. In this blog, I store details on an article in the database, such as headline, author, etc... Then, I write the article in word, save it as an html document, and upload the file to django. All of this can be done through the builtin admin page. But the reason I need to upload an entire folder is because if I use images in my article, Word places them inside a folder with the same name as the article and appends '.fld' to the folder name. Let's say I save an article as 'test.html'. It saves that file and any other files it needs in a folder named 'test.fld' right next to the html file. If I could upload the article and folder along with it, it would make life a lot easier. That being said, the django documentation for uploading multiple files sucks. I was wondering if anyone could give me clearer explanation on how to do this. And if possible, how to upload an entire folder.

Comment: Not exactly solution you are looking for, but what if you would accept compressed archives? I am sure there is a module to get them un zipped/rared/tared directly in python, or you could just use subprocess. Might also save you some bandwidth in case you have a lot of photos etc.

Comment: That is actually a much better approach. Saves space and much less issues that can arise. Thanks!